# Edge set tetrahedra

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, solid-geometry, tiling

For a set of 6 edge values, up to 60 distinct tetrahedra can be made in 30 mirrored pairs.

> Can a tetrahedron with a given edge set exist entirely inside a second tetrahedron with the same edge set?

Here's a picture of a sample sixty tetrahedra with the same edge set, all with the same centroid.

[image: sixty tetra]

For this picture $x^3-8 x^2+8=0, x\approx 1.0748$ and the edgeset is $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5)$.  The local minimum for the volume difference between the largest and smallest power-edged tetrahedra seems to be at $12-14 x^2-8 x^4-9 x^6-11 x^{10}-12 x^{12}+13 x^{14}+14 x^{16} =0$, with $x\approx 1.0743129936059068432$

The edgeset (7,8,9,10,11,12) also gives 60 distinct tetrahedra. The edgeset (2,3,4,5,6,7) only yields 8.

[image: 8 tetra]

Here's a ridiculously hard question.

> Can 60 distinct tetrahedra with the same edgeset be solidly packed together to make a convex polyhedron?

Comment: What is an "edge set"?

Comment: an edge set is the lengths of the edges in a tetrahedron

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Can a tetrahedron with a given edge set exist entirely inside a second tetrahedron with the same edge set?

Comment: If you have two exactly same tetrahedra, one is completely inside the other.

Comment: As soon as I saw that first image, I knew this was an Ed Pegg question.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the longest edge length in one tetrahedron can fit anywhere in the second tetrahedron other than coincident to the same longest edge.

Comment: I think that's almost right, @JoshB., but if an "edge set" allows a specific number of repetitions then each longest edge of the inner tetrahedron must coincide with one of the longest edges of the outer tetrahedron. It's not clear what the OP's intentions are regarding repetitions.

Comment: What does "*solidly packed together*" mean? In particular, a series of regular tetrahedra can be stacked to make a skew prism, but I presume that doesn't count?

Comment: Ah, *distinct*. Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a tetrahedron with a given edge set exist entirely inside a second tetrahedron with the same edge set?

If the edge lengths are distinct the longest edge must coincide, so *inside* must be interpreted as including the surface.

To reduce the number of variables when setting up a search, it's convenient to place one vertex at the origin and one vertex on the $x$-axis. Wlog let this edge along the $x$-axis be the longest and of length $1$; one other vertex be on the $xy$-plane in the positive quadrant; and the final vertex have positive $z$. Then it may be necessary to rotate one of the tetrahedra around the $x$-axis.

I set up a computer search, and on the basis of KISS I didn't initally include the rotation around the $x$-axis. I generate the five remaining lengths randomly, and get a moderate number of hits. Out of 100000 randomly generated edge sets, 1298 give one or more solutions.

For a concrete example, edge lengths $1$, $0.491608192441803$, $0.825600445654988$, $0.472933445811706$, $0.594917355382311$, $0.426403530140595$ give tetrahedra $(0, 0, 0); (1, 0, 0); (0.2800313, 0.4040558, 0); (0.4348697, 0.04946157, 0.1791869)$ and $(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0.2800313, 0.4040558, 0), (0.5860534, 0.05409243, 0.08684553)$ which share three vertices but where the fourth vertex of the second tetrahedron is well inside the first tetrahedron.

A solution which only has two vertices in common is $1$, $0.762268094235225$, $0.458549573765392$, $0.695390043172701$, $0.471136764842615$, $0.240386575106711$ with tetrahedron $(0, 0, 0); (1, 0, 0); (0.6853924, 0.3336013, 0); (0.6307988, 0.213046, 0.200678)$ containing tetrahedron $(0, 0, 0); (1, 0, 0); (0.2383665, 0.03109829, 0); (0.6366498, 0.2551774, 0.1145811)$; I haven't calculated how far it can be rotated while remaining inside, but it must be a non-zero amount, so you can lift the third vertex off the $xy$-plane and make the longest edge the only point of surface contact.

Comment: Nice!  The second question is silly-hard, so I'll give it to you.